# How to group by numeric value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called test. Its having data as below. I need to get each grouped highest numeric value from test table.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------+------+
| id | value   | name  |
+----+-------+------+
|  1  |    1   | row1  |
|  2  |    1.2 | row2  |
|  3  |    1.5 | row3  |
|  4  |    2   | row4  |
|  5  |    3   | row5  |
|  6  |    3.1 | row6  |
|  7  |    3.6 | row7  |
|  8  |    4   | row8  |
|  9  |    5   | row9  |
|  10 |    5.1 | row10 |
+----+-------+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I need the result should be look like below to get maximum value in each number group:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | value   | name  |
+----+-------+------+
|  1  |    1.5 | row1  |
|  4  |    2   | row4  |
|  7  |    3.6 | row7  |
|  8  |    4   | row8  |
|  10 |    5.1 | row10 |
+----+-------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any one can help me ?How the query would be?

Comment: What you get and what you want just mention

Comment: How do you group the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

[**SQLFIDDLEEXample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c19938/8)

```
select t1.id,
       t1.value,
       t1.name
from Table1 t1
left join Table1 t2
  ON floor(t2.value) = floor(t1.value)
  AND t2.value > t1.value
WHERE t2.value is null
```

Result:

```
| ID | VALUE |  NAME |
|----|-------|-------|
|  3 |   1.5 |  row3 |
|  4 |     2 |  row4 |
|  7 |   3.6 |  row7 |
|  8 |     4 |  row8 |
| 10 |   5.1 | row10 |
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. Its rocking.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to group the data by the integer part of your `value` column. If that is right, it can be done like this:

```
select max(t.id) as id, max(t.value) as value
from test as t
group by floor(t.value)
```

And if you want to get the matching names, you can join this result with your original table:

```
select a.*, t.name
from 
    (
        select max(t.id) as id, max(t.value) as value
        from test as t
        group by floor(t.value)
    ) as a
    inner join test as t on a.id = t.id
```

By the way, please be more specific when describing your problem

Answer (score 1):

if you have unique values for different rows you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE VALUE IN(
    SELECT MAX(value) FROM test GROUP BY FLOOR(value)
)
```